# Show maven project build properties in Spring Boot HTML page

Tags: java, html, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've only started looking at Spring Boot and its various modules, but I was trying to work out how to embed into a HTML page as part of a Spring Boot application the project version, that comes from the maven project.version variable?

So basically I want some anchor that is in the HTML page, then when rendered, or built is replaced with the maven project.version variable.  I saw somewhere that I can reference a maven property in spring boot using a @@ notation, but when I add @project.version@, that's what I see in the webpage when the application is running, so what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem. After some research on how to get the maven project version in a Spring Boot application I found a answer. My solution is not elegant and I'm not proud of it, but it works.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/jboss</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.html</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ..
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is an easier way of doing this, but this is how we did the exact same thing...

In our pom.xml file we set a property called `gateway.version`.  We set that property to be equal to the `${project.version}` value.  The `${project.version}` is a maven placeholder for your `<version>0.0.1</version>` value.

Example pom.xml:

```
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Web Application</name>

<properties>
    <gateway.version>${project.version}</gateway.version>
</properties>
...
```

Then through maven resource attribute filtering we'll get the `gateway.version` property filled in our properties file.

Example properties file:

```
gateway.version=${gateway.version}
```

Then in your jsp, template, whatever your view technology is...  Access this property value.

We actually set this property value in a Domain Object and added that domain object to every request.